# Please explain what this code means

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm going through the tutorial at the address: http://www.stanford.edu/~ouster/cgi-bin/cs142-spring12/lecture.php?topic=event.

And I don't understand about code at the lines that I have marked with asterisks.

```
function Dragger(id) {
    this.isMouseDown = false;
    this.element = document.getElementById(id);
    var obj = this;
    this.element.onmousedown = function(event) {
        obj.mouseDown(event);
    }
}

Dragger.prototype.mouseDown = function(event) {
    var obj = this;
    this.oldMoveHandler = document.body.onmousemove;  /******/
    document.body.onmousemove = function(event) {     /******/
        obj.mouseMove(event);
    }
    this.oldUpHandler = document.body.onmouseup;      /******/
    document.body.onmouseup = function(event) {       /******/
        obj.mouseUp(event);
    }
    this.oldX = event.clientX;
    this.oldY = event.clientY;
    this.isMouseDown = true;
}

Dragger.prototype.mouseMove = function(event) {
    if (!this.isMouseDown) {
        return;
    }
    this.element.style.left = (this.element.offsetLeft
            + (event.clientX - this.oldX)) + "px";
    this.element.style.top = (this.element.offsetTop
            + (event.clientY - this.oldY)) + "px";
    this.oldX = event.clientX;
    this.oldY = event.clientY;
}

Dragger.prototype.mouseUp = function(event) {
    this.isMouseDown = false;
    document.body.onmousemove = this.oldMoveHandler;   /******/
    document.body.onmouseup = this.oldUpHandler;       /******/
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, your "lines that you have emphasized" are the lines that start and end with "**", right?

Comment: I'm feeling a little ಠ_ಠ over a 2012 tutorial that advices old-fashioned intrusive event handler binding.

Comment: @Pointy I hope this is a copy pasted course coming from years ago

Comment: There's a good example of this pattern with comments here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror Basically, each elements can only have one `onmousemove` handler, so if you're trying to add a new one and one already exists, save and call the existing one in your new handler. Note that using `onmousemove` is totally unnecessary, because you can attach an unlimited number of events with `.addEventListener("mousemove", function() { ... })`

Comment: Yes!, "lines that I have emphasized" are the line that have /*****/

Comment: @Pointy CS 142: Introduction to how ⁿᵒᵗ to develop web applications.

Comment: They are just starting to introduce JavaScript in most computer science programs, so that isin't surprising...

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the this.oldMoveHandler references are to store whatever event handlers a previous developer of the page may have added to "document.body.onmousemove", with the goal of not interrupting whatever behavior that developer no doubt spend painful hours to build. It goes like this:

1. Press down with the mouse, store the old handler, add our fancy dragging handler.
2. Move the mouse, lovely dragging behavior occurs.
3. Release the mouse, dragging behavior stops, restore old handler (even if it's null).

This is a way to stay out of the way of previous code, although it's a bad solution. The much preferred way is to use addEventListener/removeEventListener or attachEvent/detachEvent for barbaric IE browsers. These functions are designed so that multiple handlers can subscribe to the same event without stepping on each other. Here's some good reading:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Answer (score 0):

Setting `document.body.onmousemove` is one (ugly) way to listen for `mousemove` events on the `document.body` element.

Therefore,  `this.oldMoveHandler = document.body.onmousemove;` is simply storing a reference to the event handler function, if any.

Please note that using [`element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener) is preferred for attaching event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments the use of intrusive event handling is very old fashioned and not recommended now.

However to answer your question the code is implementing drag and drop, when the **mousedown** event is triggered by a mouse press the current event handlers for **mouseup** and **mouseover** (first 4 lines of marked code) are "saved" and replaced by the event handlers that will perform the drag and drop.

When the dragged element is "dropped" i.e. the **mouseup** event fires, the **mousemove** and **mouseup** event handlers are replaced with the original event handlers that were saved (last 2 lines of marked code)